# I've commited and pushed a new feature_branch on git but it doesn't show the changes on that branch after commit/push in central repository on github

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea, version-control

So at first I just created the new branch in IntelliJ on the fly, made the adjustments to the code, push/commit the file. immediately after that I checked the central repository on github and there was no such branch. So I created the same branch directly on the github page, and when I tried to commit and push the changes this time using gitBash (even though I don't know if there is a difference) I got this message: "On branch feature_branch
nothing to commit, working tree clean"

I checked the central repository and my changes still weren't there. I've lost a whole day going back and forth I even reinstalled intelliJ.

Also I think it's important to note that the file I commit had several errors (it's like the class that I was working on had no Idea of other Classes in the same package), and intelliJ wasn't showing compiler errors when I wrote the code... I tried checking the Build Project Automatically checkbox in settings and it still doesn't work... I tried changing the project SDK, still doesn't work.

Could the problem be in IntelliJ, and if so, where and what should I look for? I'm completely lost and need some help. Any ideas on what should I try are welcome.

Comment: It sounds like you've committed but *not* pushed. What happens if you just run `git push` in the terminal?

Comment: and what does `git status` say?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that was it essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Check `git log` if there is your change comitted, check `git status` if there is anything left to commit.
Try to check also your current branch `git branch` if you are on feature branch.

Comment: Seems like I intelliJ doesn't set the upstream for the newly created branch. So I deleted the local branch from gitBash, created a new one and did it manually. I don't get why intelliJ's VCS doesn't work properly  though :/